# how to split a string_view into multiple string_view objects without any dynamic allocations

Tags: c++, optimization, c++20, stringtokenizer, string-view

The snippet below comes from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c/28788127#28788127) answer.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void tokenize(std::string str, std::vector<string> &token_v){
    size_t start = str.find_first_not_of(DELIMITER), end=start;

    while (start != std::string::npos){
        // Find next occurence of delimiter
        end = str.find(DELIMITER, start);
        // Push back the token found into vector
        token_v.push_back(str.substr(start, end-start));
        // Skip all occurences of the delimiter to find new start
        start = str.find_first_not_of(DELIMITER, end);
    }
}
```

Now for a buffer like this:

```
std::array<char, 150> buffer;
```

I want to have a `sting_view` (that points to the buffer) and pass it to the tokenizer function and the tokens should be returned in the form of `std::string_view`s via an out parameter (and not a vector) and also it will return the numbers of tokens that were extracted. The interface looks like this:

```
size_t tokenize( const std::string_view inputStr,
                 const std::span< std::string_view > foundTokens_OUT,
                 const size_t expectedTokenCount )
{
    // implementation
}

int main( )
{
    std::array<char, 150> buffer { " @a hgs -- " };
    const std::string_view sv { buffer.data( ), buffer.size( ) };
    const size_t expectedTokenCount { 4 };

    std::array< std::string_view, expectedTokenCount > foundTokens; // the span for storing found tokens

    const size_t num_of_found_tokens { tokenize( sv, foundTokens, expectedTokenCount ) };

    if ( num_of_found_tokens == expectedTokenCount )
    {
        // do something
        std::clog << "success\n" << num_of_found_tokens << '\n';
    }

    for ( size_t idx { }; idx < num_of_found_tokens; ++idx )
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted( foundTokens[ idx ] ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

I would appreciate it if someone could implement a similar tokenize function but for `string_view` that splits based on space and tab characters. I tried to write one myself but it didn't work as expected (didn't support the tab). Also, I want this function to stop the work and return `expectedTokenCount + 1` if the number of tokens found in `inputStr` exceeds the `expectedTokenCount`. This is obviously more efficient.

Here is my dummy version:

```
size_t tokenize( const std::string_view inputStr,
                 const std::span< std::string_view > foundTokens_OUT,
                 const size_t expectedTokenCount )
{
    if ( inputStr.empty( ) )
    {
        return 0;
    }

    size_t start { inputStr.find_first_not_of( ' ' ) };
    size_t end { start };

    size_t foundTokensCount { };

    while ( start != std::string_view::npos && foundTokensCount < expectedTokenCount )
    {
        end = inputStr.find( ' ', start );
        foundTokens_OUT[ foundTokensCount++ ] = inputStr.substr( start, end - start );
        start = inputStr.find_first_not_of( ' ', end );
    }

    return foundTokensCount;
}
```

Note: The ranges library does not have proper support yet (at least on GCC) so I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Some programmer dude Yes but I guess you didn't read my intentions. I do not want to return a vector at all. That's why I am placing the `string_view`s (i.e. tokens) in a `std::array` (`foundTokens`) that lives on the stack of `main`.

Comment: "*I tried to write one myself but it didn't work as expected (didn't support the tab).*" You should at least show what you tried.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I put it in the answer. Have a look, please.

Comment: So you're only issue with the code you have it that it doesn't support spaces AND tabs? And you want someone to write that code for you... ?

Comment: @super Yes, I want a proper implementation or at least some guidance on how to do it.

Comment: Did you know that `find_first_not_of` can accept *character sequence* as the first parameter like `inputStr.find_first_not_of(" \t")`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Oh ok. I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to write one myself but it didn't work as expected (didn't
> support the tab).

If you want to support splitting with spaces and tabs, then you can use another overload of `find_first_not_of`:

```
size_type find_first_not_of(const CharT* s, size_type pos = 0) const;
```

which will finds the first character equal to none of characters in string pointed to by `s`.

So your implementation only needs to change `find_first_not_of(' ')` and `find(' ')` to `find_first_not_of(" \t")` and `find_first_of(" \t")`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/frsnhc9fh)

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation (which I wrote earlier), that can handle things like inputs that start with one or more delimiters, have repeated delimiters and ends one or more delimiters :

It uses string_views for everything, so no memory allocation, but be careful you don't throw away the input strings too early. string_views are after all non-owning.

online demo : https://onlinegdb.com/tytGlOVnk

```
#include <vector>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

auto tokenize(std::string_view string, std::string_view delimiters)
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> substrings;
    if (delimiters.size() == 0ul)
    {
        substrings.emplace_back(string);
        return substrings;
    }

    auto start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters);
    auto end_pos = start_pos;
    auto max_length = string.length();

    while (start_pos < max_length)
    {
        end_pos = std::min(max_length, string.find_first_of(delimiters, start_pos));

        if (end_pos != start_pos)
        {
            substrings.emplace_back(&string[start_pos], end_pos - start_pos);
            start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters, end_pos);
        }
    }

    return substrings;
}

int main()
{
    std::string_view test{ "The, quick! and brown fox. Jumped : over the lazy dog, or did he?" };

    auto tokens = tokenize(test, " ,!.?:");

    for (const auto token : tokens)
    {
        std::cout << token << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```